# UILabel with NSAttributedString does work in iOS 7 but doesn't in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, uilabel, uistoryboard

I have an UILabel with the following settings set up in my storyboard:

[image: UILabel settings in storyboard]

In my code, I set the corresponding text for the label using the UILabel's `setText:` message. This works pretty fine in iOS 7. [image: iOS 7 view]

However, when starting the app on an iOS 6 device or simulator, the UILabel's settings are ignored, completely: [image: iOS 6 view]

If I set the UILabel's attributedText property in Code, this somewhat works, but I really don't want to programatically style all the labels I have already set up and working in iOS 7 in my Storyboard.

Any suggestions here?

Thanks

**Update:**

I found out meanwhile, that the attributedText-settings I set in the Storyboard are not even applied to the UILabel object in iOS 6:

```
iOS 6:

(lldb) po [cell.eventName.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL]
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0xb189240> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 4, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSShadow = "NSShadow {0, -1} color = {(null)}";
}

iOS 7:

(lldb) po [cell.eventName.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL]
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0xc1c3cc0> font-family: \"HelveticaNeue-Light\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 21.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 2, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 4, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSShadow = "NSShadow {0, -1} color = {(null)}";
}
```

As you can see, the font I selected in the Storyboard differs from the font the attributedText of the UILabel has assigned in iOS 6, but not in iOS 7.

**Update 2:**

I created an example application, download here: [Example application](http://hd.mkswap.net/share/b1nxNFGY3vnhKZkzMakFtlw.zip)

With this application, you can perfectly reproduce the issue. Run in Simulator with first iOS 7, then iOS 6. You will see the result as explained here.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use the attributedText property.

Try this:

```
NSAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
    initWithString:@"Opening Event" 
        attributes:[label.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL]];
label.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: Does not work, but I found out something interesting. Amended the question therefor.

Comment: Actually, I further found out that this *does* work, but only if previously no setText: message has been sent to the UILabel. Guess that's still not the expected behaviour..

Comment: @TimoJosten this is a vital piece of info, was bugging me for ages. I had used [label setText:@""] to clear a label, but this messes up the attributes